# MedianBlur() calculate max kernel size

Tags: opencv

I want to use MedianBlur function with very high Ksize, like 301 or more. But if I pass ksize too high, sometimes the function will crash. The error message is:

```
OpenCV Error: (k < 16) in cv::medianBlur_8u_O1, in file ../opencv\modules\imgproc\src\smooth.cpp
```

(I use opencv4nodejs, but I also tried the original OpenCV 3.4.6).
I did reduce the ksize in a try/catch loop, but not so effective, since I have to work with videos.

I did checkout the OpenCV source code and did some research.
In OpenCV 3.4.6, the crash come from line 241, file opencv\modules\imgproc\src\median_blur.simd.hpp:

```
for ( k = 0; k < 16 ; ++k )
{
    sum += H.coarse[k];
    if ( sum > t )
    {
         sum -= H.coarse[k];
         break;
    }
}
CV_Assert( k < 16 ); // Error here
```

t is caculated base on ksize. But sum and H.coarse array's calculations are quite complicated.

Did further researches, I found a scientific document about the algorithm: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321690537_Efficient_Scalable_Median_Filtering_Using_Histogram-Based_Operations

I am trying to read but honestly, I don't understand too much.

How do I calculate the maximum ksize with a given image?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum kernel size is determined from the bit depth of the image. As mentioned in the publication you cited:

> "An 8-bit value is limited to a max value of 255. Our goal is to
> support larger kernel sizes, including kernels that are greater in
> size than 17 × 17, thus the larger 32-bit data type is used"

so for an image of data type CV_8U the maximum kernel size is 255.